# How to associate volume knob to foobar volume?

Tags: audio, foobar2000

My laptop has a volume knob by the side and it's associated to the playback device currently used. Since I use a DAC that requires such level to be at 100%, I cannot use the knob to control the volume and have to rely on foobar volume control. How can I associate the knob to foobar volume instead?

Comment: Whats a "knob" and DAC? Insert links to explain them for us

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the hardware knob on your laptop is a digital control (rotary encoder) and not an analog control (potentiometer). If that is the case, it will likely act a master volume control for the default playback device and any applications using the default audio device.

Here's how you can use the knob to control master volume without affecting the volume/gain setting of the USB DAC:

First, in the Windows control panel, change the default output device to the laptop's internal sound card (or to a device other than the USB DAC).

[image: Windows default audio device settings]

Next, go to Foobar preferences and change the output device to DS: USB DAC.

[image: Foobar output device setting]

This should allow you to use the knob on your laptop to adjust the volume of everything BUT the device to which Foobar is outputting audio. Please note that the knob on your laptop will not change the position of the volume slider in Foobar. I hope this helps.

Comment: The knob is as shown in this picture `http://www.laptopreviews.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/DSC_0028.jpg`

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the way a DAC should be used. AFAIK, I must set the computer volume at some level (maximum?) and only change it through Foobar. But if I use the knob, it's the computer volume that changes.

Comment: I implement what you said. The result is that when I use the knob, neither the Foobar volume nor the computer volume changes, even though the fact that I'm using the knob is acknowledged on the screen as shown here `https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8NxxImHTPRLMXJ5eHBjRDFzOGs/edit?usp=sharing`. Is there a way to use the knob to control Foobar volume?